# Does the PlatformSDK folder in VS2010 ever get updated?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I've been battling error C2733 (`second C linkage of overloaded function '_interlockedbittestandset' not allowed`), and in doing some investigations, I've found what I believe to be the problem.

I have Visual Studio 2010 Professional installed on my system, along with SP1 and a number of hot-fixes, and I noticed that the *PlatformSDK* folder that came with the application is now down-level. The SDK that came with the application is located at:

```
Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\PlatformSDK
```

As a result of installing SP1 and the various hot-fixes, I now also have this platform SDK available to me:

```
Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A
```

The problem is that Visual Studio defaults all of the VC++ Directories to the former path, which results in the errors. If I manually change the include path to point to the newer location, the errors go away.

1. Were the Visual Studio 2010 SP1 installers supposed to update the *PlatformSDK* folder where Visual Studio is installed? Or is that always going to be down-level as updates are applied?
2. How do I force the VC++ Directories paths to be the same across all projects (since VS is defaulting to the wrong / outdated location)?

Comment: The practice of VS keeping its own copy of the SDK in the PlatformSDK subdirectory ended quite a while ago, VS2005 was the last one.  You'd have to assume that *somebody* forced this copy, possibly in an attempt to keep old projects compatible.  And probably monkeyed with the registry keys as well.

Comment: I don't recall ever copying anything by hand. I simply installed VS 2010 using their installer. I should mention that I still have 2005 installed; perhaps that screwed something up?